# Como comunicar la página del popup con el background.js en extensiones de google?

Tags: extensión-google-chrome

Estoy creando una extensión sencilla para google chrome y no logro entender cómo comunicar la página de fondo con el la del popup. estoy utilizando vue.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"extension de prueba",
  "description":"..",
  "version":"0.1",
  "browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"index.html",
    "default_title":"mmmm"
  },
  "permissions":["tabs"],
  "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"], 
        "persistent": false 
    }
}
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   {{ saludo }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
alert(mensaje); // ERROR mensaje no esta definida

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
     saludo:'hola mundo'
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style>
body{
  background-color: #001835;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
}

</style>
```

background.js

```
'use strict'
let mensaje = 'HOLA';
```

En resumen lo que me gustaria seria enviar la variable mensaje hasta el componente App.vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi este problema con la combinación de este método `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` y el evento `chrome.runtime.onMessage` . de esta forma se logra la comunicación del background y el script del popup y viceversa:

background.js

```
   'use strict'
    var mensaje = 'HOLA';
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: mensaje}, function(response) { console.log("mensaje enviado")});
```

App.vue

```
    <template>
          <div id="app">
           {{ saludo }}
          </div>
    </template>

        <script>
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponde){   
            alert(request.msg); //HOLA
            return true;
     });

          export default {
          name: 'app',
          data () {
            return {
             saludo:'hola mundo'
            }
          }
        }

        </script>

        <style>
        body{
          background-color: #001835;
          width: 400px;
          height: 250px;
        }

        </style>
```